# Use a model to create an object in a component

Tags: ember.js

I'm in Ember 3.4

I can create an EmberObject with

```
let course = EmberObject.extend({
  duration: null,
  level: null
});

course.create({ duration: '7', level: 'medium' });
```

But I already have a model for courses, defined in `'app/models/course.js'`.

I wonder if I can "import" the model in the component and use it to create the object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yeah, you can call extend / create on any ember object.

Though, if you're wanting ember-data to be aware of the model, you may want to inject the store via a service.

like this:

```
import Component from '@ember/component';
import { service } from '@ember-decorators/service';

export default class extends Component {
  @service store;

  async someFunction() {
    const course = this.store.createRecord('course', {
      duration: '7', 
      level: 'medium'
    });

    // maybe other logic

    await course.save();

  }
}
```

To import anything from models'

```
import ModelName from 'appname/app/models/model-file';
```

Comment: I will keep this great answer because I will need it soon, but for some models I do not want to persist data. I just want to "use" them for screen purposes. I think that keeping all in the models directory should be better than creating ad-hoc objects. I do not know how to import and extend a "foreing" model in my component.

Comment: What version of ember? If you aren't using ember-data things, you can just use JavaScript

Comment: Ember 3.4. I use Ember data for most of the models, and for remote persistence. But there are objects and enumerables that I use just for volatile screens. It works fine with plain ember objects, as in my example. But I don't like to define those objects inside the component (some of them will be reused in other components). It seems to me that using models should be a better idea. Or maybe not. I do not know how to import them.

Comment: I've updated my answer with how to import things from models :) hope this helps

Comment: After some tests, in the end, when you are going to work seriously with the model, the way to go is inyecting the store, as described in the accepted answer. But for simple purposes, like displaying volatile things on the screen, using a model is an overkill. EmberObject is enough. Now I know it. :-)